# Auto fill in text in search box on gridview in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a button on the ribbon of the contactgrid in microsoft dynamics crm 2011. When I press the button, I'm reading an id from an external device after that i want this id to be paste into the searchbox. So my gridview will be filter automatically on the id read from that device.

But how can I call the searchbox with javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can access it w JQuery by its html id, like this:

```
var ctrl = $("#crmGrid_findCriteria");
```

It is a text input, so you should be able to access it like this:

```
$("#crmGrid_findCriteria").text('some_text');
```

I discovered the ID of the control using the IE Developer Tools (F12)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. i was thinking about this sollution, but the problem is that i open a popup window to read the id. And i need to find how i can transfer the code from this popup window to the searchbox.

Comment: check out the JS keyword 'opener', it references the window that opened the pop-up window... think opener.document.getElementById('some_id');